# Is there a .exe out there which takes a file as input and then searches your filesystem replacing anything with the same name?

Tags: software-rec, file-management, file-transfer

Before I commit to the 5 minutes it should take to write this I figure I should ask if it isn't already out there as part of something I may not have heard of.  I'm looking for a program that takes a file [input_file] and directory as input, and then searches that directory and all sub directories for any files with the same name as input_file.  Renames anything it finds and then copies over input_file.

Looking for a windows solution so something .exe or easy to compile preferred.

Is this the right place to ask this?  Based on something I just read this will get closed as off topic... uh.. please no?

Ok it you think its off topic... is there a dos shell command to do this?  That's gotta be on topic.

Comment: The question is on topic.  It is a sufficiently specific and reasonably well worded software recommendation question and is within the bounds of the [FAQ].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`find`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/findutils.htm) will help you find the files, and [`cp -b`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) will rename the file first if it already exists.

```
find some\dir -name input_file -execdir cp -b path\to\input_file . ;
```

Comment: find is like, the best program of all time +1